# Outlook addin - move mail in a shared inbox

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin

Assume that I have two mail inboxes;

```
example1@outlook.com (my account)
    Inbox (private)
     ...
     ...

SharedEmail
    Inbox
        JunkFolder
```

And let's say mail arrives at SharedEmail _> Inbox. Is it possible to programatically move mail from Inbox -> JunkFolder in **SharedEmail**?

Currently I use

```
var junkFolder = explorer.Application.
            ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
            (OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Folders["JunkFolder"]
```

and use the `Move` method from *MailItem* type to actually move the mail. However, that seems to move mail to "JunkFolder" in my private inbox (example1@outlook.com).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GetSharedDefaultFolder` instead of `GetDefaultFolder`.

Comment: @H. Pauwelyn - yes, that does provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks for yout reply. What decides if a shared folder is default? I mean, what happens if I have two shared folders?

Comment: GetSharedDefaultFolder  takes Recipient object as a parameter (you can use Namespace.CreateRecipient)

Comment: Or, if the store is already added tp the profile, find it in the Namespace.Stores collection and use Store.GetDefaultFolder - it will return the default folder fro that particular mailbox.

Comment: Dmitry: What do you mean by if the store is already added to the profile? How is this done? Perhaps that' method is easier.

Comment: Can you see the store in question in the folder list in Outlook?

Comment: Yeps, but when I enumerate stores I only get my personal inbox in that list (using DisplayName attribute). Shouldn't the shared appear as well?

Comment: Are you sure you see the store in the folder tree view? Or in "Other Calendars" or "Shared Calendars"?

Comment: Yes, it's there. I noticed now that I do find the store, but apparently  it's not a data file store - is this required?

Comment: Which one is it? What do you mean by "not a data file store"? Why does it matter?

Comment: Both. But when retreiving the default folder for the shared mailbox store, the Folders.Count property is 0 even though it has childfolders. When I do the same for my private, all lists fine. One difference is that my private is a data file store, and the shared is not. Any clue?

Comment: This is to be expected - when you call GetSharedDefaultFolder for a folder that is cached in the local OST file, Outlook returns only that folder without any subfolders, which are not cached. The only workaround is to reopen the folder in the online mode, which you can do using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (any language).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Any example of doing this via Redemption?

Comment: Try to create an instance of the RDOSession object, sets its MAPIOBJECT property to Namespace.MAPIOBJECT from OOM< then call RDOSession.GetSharedMailbox / RDOStore.GetDefaultFolder. You might need to provide Redemption with the user credentials(RDOSession,Creadentials.Add) to let it retrieve the autodiscover XML to be used by GetSharedMailbox